# Avoid ExperimentalMaterial3Api-OptIn in a Kotlin Android-App

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-material3, kotlin-experimental

Using Jetpack Compose and Android Studio, I have been trying to learn developing apps.

I wanted to have a Text Widget display exactly what was typed into a text field.

When building this, following the answer of this question ([Custom class for holding multiple states in Jetpack Compose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73123718/custom-class-for-holding-multiple-states-in-jetpack-compose)), I build up some code which seemingly requires an Experimental Material3 Api.

I don't know which part of my code needs the experimental API and I would like to avoid this.

I tried with the following code

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun NameGreeter() {
    var content by remember {
        mutableStateOf("Editable Text")
    }
    Column {
        Text(text = content)
        TextField(value = content, onValueChange = {
            content = it
        })
    }
}
```

and the compiler prompted me with an error message which would inform me that this function needs experimental API support of type "class".

Where do I see which classes really are part of the experimental API and do you know alternatives to avoid them?

Comment: Experimental API's are usually components in the Beta or Release candidate state but that are not yet stable. They will almost always be release on the next update so there is not much to worry about.

If you remove the OptIn from the code Android studio will tell you what component need that OptIn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Where do I see which classes really are part of the experimental API
> and do you know alternatives to avoid them?

He stated the **risk** of the relevant structure in the documentation.

```
@RequiresOptIn(message = "This material API is experimental and is likely to change or to be removed in the future.")
@Retention(value = AnnotationRetention.BINARY)
annotation ExperimentalMaterial3Api
```

> This material API is experimental and is likely to change or to be
> removed in the future.

You can see all `experimental` versions by searching [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/refs/heads/androidx-main/compose/material3/material3/api/).

Sample [1.0.0-beta01](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/refs/heads/androidx-main/compose/material3/material3/api/1.0.0-beta01.txt) version. If you search for **"ExperimentalMaterial3Api"** you can see it.